# Parse DynamoDB List DataType

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I am building an angular 8 application and am storing JSON data in a list data type in DynamoDB. I can insert the records just fine and can query the table for the data but I'm having issues grabbing the data in the list data type.

[image: Data in DynamoDB]

Here is how it looks in a console log

[image]

I don't have any issues grabbing the String data values, only the nested data in the List data type.

Comment: can you elaborate what is your issue with the List data type?

Comment: The issue I'm having is I'm unable to parse the list type data and assign to a variable. I have a repeating row that I used to generate the data as seen in the first image. I need to be able to re-populate the repeating row if the user wants to edit something. I don't have any issues parsing and getting the String data, it's only the list data shown in the second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue is related parsing the objects returned from dynamo you can use the DynamoDB Converter

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html#unmarshall-property

this will convert the returned dynamo record into a json record.

Also if you're using the sdk, consider also using the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html where it will automatically convert dynamo records into json records.

Comment: I'm actually not using the sdk to query the data but rather an angular http get call to a post . Is it possible to parse the data without using the sdk? Below is the query in the api gateway:

{
  "TableName": "Purchases",
  "IndexName": "AID-PurchaseStatus-index",
  "ProjectionExpression": "Column List",
  "KeyConditionExpression": "AID = :v1",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":v1": {
      "S": "$input.params('aid')"
    }
  },
  "ScanIndexForward": true,
  "Limit": 10000
}

Comment: ahh interesting,  you can use the integration response to map your data in dynamo. There is some examples https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/
https://medium.com/@rafacampana/rest-api-just-with-apigateway-and-dynamodb-8a9b0cd76b7a
But I don't think there is a generic converter. The best option i could think is having a Lambda between API GW and Dynamo

Comment: So there would be no way to iterate through the objects on the client side using JSON? At most I'd have 2 maybe 3 rows to iterate through. 

`var data = purchasedetail;
console.log(data.length);
console.log(data);
console.log(data[i].M.BillType.S);`

The length is returned and the data shows both rows like I showed in the image above but when I try to grab the BillType I get the following error: 

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'S' of undefined
    at AccountComponent.push../src/app/crm/accounts/account.component.ts.AccountComponent.updatePurchase...`

Comment: from your screenshots should be looking for `billType` and not `BillType`, so console.log(data[i].M.billType.S)